# How to delete a project in Xcode 5.0

Tags: ios, xcode, project

I want to delete a project from Xcode 5.0. I have done the (cmd-shift-2) and deleted the project but when i quit and re-open Xcode, I still see the project. Is there any other way of deleting projects from Xcode?

Comment: You deleted the derived data? What, specifically, do you want to delete? Everything?

Comment: Just delete the folder containing the project file. You already deleted the derived data.

Answer (score 8):

Go to File ---> Open recent ---> Clear menu

Comment: hi Rauru, it cleared everything thanks

Answer (score 5):

Go to Finder look for the project folder and delete it